# Programmatically refresh/synchronize an IntelliJ IDEA project via a plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Is there a way to programmatically refresh/synchronize an IntelliJ IDEA project via a plugin?

I'm working on an IntelliJ IDEA plugin that creates a file within the active project. And I want to refresh/synchronize the project automatically via the plugin so that the user can see the changes immediately. Is this possible in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging a bit more I came through the following solution and it worked.

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {

    // Create/Modify files

    // Get the project from the ActionEvent
    Project project = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);

    // Get the Base Dir and refresh with the following parameters
    // 'asynchronous' set to false and 'recursive' set to true
    project.getBaseDir().refresh(false,true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SyncAction for it

```
SyncProjectAction().actionPerformed(actionEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above methods work in my case. I am using huawei's DevEco.

My solution is invoke the **Sync Action** in my own action:

1. Find the Action of "sync"

```kotlin
private fun getSyncActions() {
    val actionManager = ActionManager.getInstance()
    val actionIds = actionManager.getActionIds("")
    for (id in actionIds) {
        if (id.lowercase().contains("sync")) {
            val action = actionManager.getAction(id)
            val message =
                "Action ID: " + id + " - " + action.getTemplatePresentation().text
            println(message)
        }
    }
}
```

The `Action ID` above is what we need.

2. Invoke the Sync Action with `ActionManager`

```kotlin
fun invokeAnAction() {
    // Execute asynchronously on EDT
    ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater {
        try {
            val am: ActionManager = ActionManager.getInstance()
            val syncAndRefreshProjectAction = am.getAction("YOUR ACTION ID HERE")

            if (syncAndRefreshProjectAction != null) {
                am.tryToExecute(
                    syncAndRefreshProjectAction,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    true
                )
            } else {
                // custome notify
                Notify.error("Action not found.")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Notify.error("error in get Action: $e")
            Logger.getInstance(this::class.java).error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

That works for me, and btw the **Sync Action ID** in huawei's DevEco is `Ohos.SyncAndRefresh`.